# Filling several matrices in a loop, using the name of the matrices for selecting a different matrix for each iteration of the loop?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, matrix

I think the answer to this question will be very easy but honestly I could not find a solution. I used `assign()` and `paste()` functions in order to create 25 empty matrices with a LOOP, changing the number in the name.
Thus, the names of the matrices are:
`ReturnMat_InSampleL24`,..., `ReturnMat_InSampleL48`

I know that I can use `get()` in order to also print out these matrices with a loop.

The point is I need to find a way to modify those matrices with a single loop (it will then be placed inside others, but it should not matter right now)

So I would like to achieve something like:

```
for (i in 1:25) {ReturnMat_InSampleLi[] = ...}
```

But of course doesn't work like that, we cannot put an `i` in the name inside the loop.

Here is the code for the matrixes, just in case:

```
InSamplePeriodLenghtTest = matrix(c((24:48)),ncol = 1)  
OutSamplePeriodLenghtTest = InSamplePeriodLenghtTest
PeriodsNumber1 = 170    
FactorsNumber = 8

for (i in 1:(nrow(InSamplePeriodLenghtTest))) {

  assign(paste("ReturnMat_InSampleL",InSamplePeriodLenghtTest[i],sep=""),
         matrix(c(rep(NA,(1+InSamplePeriodLenghtTest[i]) * FactorsNumber * ((PeriodsNumber1-1-InSamplePeriodLenghtTest[i])-(InSamplePeriodLenghtTest[i] * 2)+1))),
                                                       ncol = FactorsNumber)) }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I have tried to clean up your code by replacing `x` by `*` as the latter is the correct multiplication operator in R. However, the code is still not working because `PeriodsNumber1` is undefined. Please, [edit] your question and correct your code so that it will be a [mcve]. Help us to help you. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Uwe, I am sorry for the mistake. I added the missing variable, now it should work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't decipher your code, but the best way to manage a collection of related objects is with a list.  Then use the list index to operate on each element in the list, instead of creating independent objects in the environment.  Here is a simple example for creating a list of 5 matrices each with dimension of 4x4 populated by 16 random values between 1 and 100:

```
my_list <- list()
for (i in 1:5) {
      values <- sample(1:100, 16)
      my_list[[i]] <- matrix(values, nrow = 4, ncol = 4)

}
```

You could assign names to each member of the list or just operate on each member by referencing its list index value.  You could also operate on each matrix element of the list with one of the apply family of functions for example:

```
my_list_t <- lapply(my_list, function(x) t(x))
```

Will create a second list of matrices with the transposes of the matrices in the original list.

Comment: SteveM, thank you very much for your help. This makes a lot of sense. Below the edited code for creating the set of matrices:                       
   `ReturnMat_InSampleL=list()

     for (i in 1:(nrow(InSamplePeriodLenghtTest))) {
  
  ReturnMat_InSampleL[[i]] = matrix(c(rep(NA,(1+InSamplePeriodLenghtTest[i])*FactorsNumber*((PeriodsNumber1-1-InSamplePeriodLenghtTest[i])-(InSamplePeriodLenghtTest[i]*2)+1))),ncol = FactorsNumber)
  
}`

Comment: Stefano, happy to be helpful.  If you could up-vote my contribution too, that would be appreciated.

Comment: SteveM, of course is the first thing I tried to do. Unfortunately I get this "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I have fully understood OP's intension but this is what I would do.

Instead of creating 25 matrices in the global environment I would store all matrices in a list (`lom` aka *list of matrices*) where they can be handled individually as well as processed as a whole by means of `lapply()`:

```
FactorsNumber <- 8
lom <- lapply(24:48, function(i) matrix(NA, ncol = FactorsNumber, nrow = i))
names(lom) <- sprintf("ReturnMat_InSampleL%02i", seq_along(lom))
str(lom)
```

> ```
> List of 25
>  $ ReturnMat_InSampleL01: logi [1:24, 1:8] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
>  $ ReturnMat_InSampleL02: logi [1:25, 1:8] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
>  $ ReturnMat_InSampleL03: logi [1:26, 1:8] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
>  $ ReturnMat_InSampleL04: logi [1:27, 1:8] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
>  $ ReturnMat_InSampleL05: logi [1:28, 1:8] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
>  $ ReturnMat_InSampleL06: logi [1:29, 1:8] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
>  $ ReturnMat_InSampleL07: logi [1:30, 1:8] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
>  $ ReturnMat_InSampleL08: logi [1:31, 1:8] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
>  $ ReturnMat_InSampleL09: logi [1:32, 1:8] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
>  $ ReturnMat_InSampleL10: logi [1:33, 1:8] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
>  $ ReturnMat_InSampleL11: logi [1:34, 1:8] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
>  $ ReturnMat_InSampleL12: logi [1:35, 1:8] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
>  $ ReturnMat_InSampleL13: logi [1:36, 1:8] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
>  $ ReturnMat_InSampleL14: logi [1:37, 1:8] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
>  $ ReturnMat_InSampleL15: logi [1:38, 1:8] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
>  $ ReturnMat_InSampleL16: logi [1:39, 1:8] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
>  $ ReturnMat_InSampleL17: logi [1:40, 1:8] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
>  $ ReturnMat_InSampleL18: logi [1:41, 1:8] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
>  $ ReturnMat_InSampleL19: logi [1:42, 1:8] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
>  $ ReturnMat_InSampleL20: logi [1:43, 1:8] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
>  $ ReturnMat_InSampleL21: logi [1:44, 1:8] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
>  $ ReturnMat_InSampleL22: logi [1:45, 1:8] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
>  $ ReturnMat_InSampleL23: logi [1:46, 1:8] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
>  $ ReturnMat_InSampleL24: logi [1:47, 1:8] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
>  $ ReturnMat_InSampleL25: logi [1:48, 1:8] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
> ```

Note that the matrices have different numbers of rows but all 8 columns as requested.

The statement

```
names(lom) <- sprintf("ReturnMat_InSampleL%02i", seq_along(lom))
```

names the matrices in the list individually.

---

Here are some tricks when dealing with a list of matrices.

Any changes create a new object. You have to make sure that the result is stored appropriately. Note the difference between:

```
lom <- lapply(24:48, function(i) matrix(i, ncol = FactorsNumber, nrow = i))
str(lom)
```

> ```
> List of 25
>  $ : int [1:24, 1:8] 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 ...
>  $ : int [1:25, 1:8] 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 ...
>  $ : int [1:26, 1:8] 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 ...
>  $ : int [1:27, 1:8] 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 ...
> ...
> ```

```
lom[] <- lapply(24:48, function(i) matrix(i, ncol = FactorsNumber, nrow = i))
str(lom)
```

> ```
> List of 25
>  $ ReturnMat_InSampleL01: int [1:24, 1:8] 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 ...
>  $ ReturnMat_InSampleL02: int [1:25, 1:8] 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 ...
>  $ ReturnMat_InSampleL03: int [1:26, 1:8] 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 ...
>  $ ReturnMat_InSampleL04: int [1:27, 1:8] 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 ...
> ...
> ```

Assigning to `lom[]` has replaced the contents of the single elements thereby preserving the names of the elements instead of creating a completely new object.

When updating matrix elements make sure to return a complete matrix:

```
lom[] <- lapply(lom, function(m) {
  m[1, 1] <- m[1, 1] *10 
  return(m)
})
str(lom)
```

> ```
> List of 25
>  $ ReturnMat_InSampleL01: num [1:24, 1:8] 240 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 ...
>  $ ReturnMat_InSampleL02: num [1:25, 1:8] 250 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 ...
>  $ ReturnMat_InSampleL03: num [1:26, 1:8] 260 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 ...
>  $ ReturnMat_InSampleL04: num [1:27, 1:8] 270 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 ...
> ...
> ```

Updating a cell of a particular matrix:

```
lom$ReturnMat_InSampleL01[1, 1] <- lom$ReturnMat_InSampleL01[1, 1] + 2
str(lom)
```

> ```
> List of 25
>  $ ReturnMat_InSampleL01: num [1:24, 1:8] 242 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 ...
>  $ ReturnMat_InSampleL02: num [1:25, 1:8] 250 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 ...
>  $ ReturnMat_InSampleL03: num [1:26, 1:8] 260 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 ...
>  $ ReturnMat_InSampleL04: num [1:27, 1:8] 270 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 ...
> ...
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much Uwe, I will go either with your solution or SteveM's one. But I think the idea is pretty much the same, implemented in 2 different ways.

Comment: @StefanoSerio. Yes, both approaches use lists. `lapply()` is an implied `for` loop which returns a list as result.